# GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount() returns account with null fields

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I'm implementing Google Sign-in in my project, but this problem is difficult. When I'm not signed, `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity)` returns `null`, which is what it should do, according to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed-in_user).  When I restart the app, it returns a `GoogleSignInAccount`, but with all fields `null`.

Google says:

> For additional profile data that might be available, see GoogleSignInAccount. Note that any of the profile fields can be null, depending on which scopes you requested and what information the user's profile includes.

So I thought the problem would be the lack of requested information, but I properly previously defined them with:

```
GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, GoogleSignInOptions.Builder()
    .requestId()
    .requestProfile()
    .requestEmail()
    .build()
);
```

Besides, all informations comes in a perfect `GoogleSignInAccount` after signing up using the same client request above.

Answer (score 4):

In my game, when GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity) return null, I call 
startSigninIntent:

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
  GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
      GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
  Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
  startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, just in my case i used GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN. Cheers...